# Google's review rich result with "reviews" instead of "votes"

Tags: google-search, schema.org, rich-snippets

I wanted to show the Ratings on Google Search result but caught up in type selection for ratings.

We wanted to show our Reviews as Review Rating:

> [image: Reviews Rating]

but for some reason, they were appearing as Vote Rating:

> [image: Vote Rating]

Although, I've figured out a way to show it as Review Rating but was curious to find the reason behind it.

Below is the sample schema I used first which was appearing as Vote Rating

[image: Vote Rating]

```json
{
    "@context":"http://schema.org/",
    "@type":"WebPage",
    "url":"https://example.com/page-where-rating-json-is-present/",
    "aggregateRating":{
        "@type":"AggregateRating",
        "bestRating":"5",
        "worstRating":"1",
        "ratingCount":"20",
        "ratingValue":"4.6"
    }
}
```

Later I changed it to a different type of schema to test it for Review Rating and surprisingly this time it appeared as Review Rating.

[image: Reviews Rating]

```json
{
    "@context":"http://schema.org/",
    "@type":"MedicalWebPage",
    "@id":"https://example.com/page-where-rating-json-is-present/ratings",
    "name":"Sample Page",
    "headline":"Sample Page Headline.",
    "aggregateRating":{
        "@type":"AggregateRating",
        "ratingValue":"4.8",
        "reviewCount":"27",
        "bestRating":"5",
        "worstRating":"1"
    }
}
```

My webpage is actually a medical webpage so it do make more sense to use `MedicalWebPage` schema type.

I want to understand what is the reason behind it appearing as vote vs review. Is it just the Type difference? Or something else could be the reason behind it? Such as `@id`, `name`, `headline` etc.

Note: There is a slight change in `aggregateRating` section too, i.e. term
`ratingCount` was used in first example whereas term `reviewCount` was used in second example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only provide an [`AggregateRating`](https://schema.org/AggregateRating), Google Search needs a way tell whether the ratings come from reviews or not. That’s presumably what Google Search will base their decision on (possibly in addition to other signals):

- By providing [`reviewCount`](https://schema.org/reviewCount), you convey that there are reviews. In this case, the "reviews" label in the rich result makes sense.
- By providing [`ratingCount`](https://schema.org/ratingCount), you convey that there are ratings, and if you don’t also provide `reviewCount` in addition, you convey that there are no reviews. In this case, the "votes" label in the rich result makes sense.

[In their review rich result documentation](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/review#type_definitions), they just say that at least one of the two properties is required:

> At least one of `ratingCount` or `reviewCount` is required.